# Post data to Ms access Database file from GridControl

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a GridControl which reads the value from a access database and shows it in it.
Whenever i change the value in gridcontrol that value is not posted into access database file ,which is a default behavior of it.
the xaml code is:

```
 <dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True" Height="600" name = "g1">
```

and the backend code in c# is :

```
 gridControl2.ItemsSource = new    InputBssDataSetTableAdapters.Input_bss1TableAdapter().GetData().DefaultView;
```

but i want to modify the value of the Access database file whenever i change the value in the gridcontrol.

please suggest me the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the grid control has saved all the changes made to the currently focused row. In this instance, you should call the [DataViewBase.CommitEditing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_CommitEditingtopic) method.
Then [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `Update()` method on your data adapter.

Related examples:
 [How to: Posting Data to a Connected Database](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6285)
 [How to: Post Values to the DXGrid Data Source Immediately After Changing a Cell Value](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9429)

Comment: I have tried the 2nd link which you gave ,but the new edited values are not posting anywhere in the database..
kindly try that and let me know my mistake...

Comment: Please anyone can answer that..??